How to trigger only one suspense to fallback in a page
I am using Next.js and I have the following structure
<Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
  <ServerWrapper>
    <ComponentA />
  <ServerWrapper/>
</Suspense>

<Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
  <ServerWrapper>
    <ComponentB />
  <ServerWrapper/>
</Suspense>

In this structure, when I click some button in ComponentA, I want the ComponentA fetch the data again and turn into loading. But at the same time, ComponentB remain unchanged (No data fetching and no loading state)
How could we do that?
I have tried to put the key prop in the Suspense but it is just weird, the component will wait for other component to complete the await then turn into loading
